# SCSS modules autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, types, sass, vite

How to get hints classes using scss modules in react with typescript and Vite,

I tried `typed-scss-modules` but this package is a cli so when I don't start server it will won't work, also I tried `typescript-plugin-css-modules` but in this approach I need to change some settings of my VSCode and I'am not sure how about people which using e.g. WebStorm, so after some researching I found package called `vite-plugin-sass-dts` but for this package it is necessary to add another package and last option is VSCode extension but the it will works only for me, So my question is it is any other solution to get scss autocomplete after imports styles ??